# Sum returning null

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a problem with a Ruby SQL look up function: it always returns a null.

Here is the terminal output:

```
SELECT COUNT("point_store_items"."point_cost") 
FROM "point_store_items" 
INNER JOIN "point_store_items_point_store_orders" 
ON "point_store_items"."id" = "point_store_items_point_store_orders"."point_store_item_id" 
WHERE "point_store_items_point_store_orders"."point_store_order_id" IS NULL
```

The code causing this problem is:

```
def self.pointcost
  self.count(:point_cost)
end
```

If this code is changed to say

```
def self.pointcost
  40
end
```

it has no issues except the prices always listed is 40, not what should come from the database.

Relevant Model Code:

```
class PointStoreItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :point_cost
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders, :class_name => "PointStoreOrder"
  has_many :users, :through => :orders
  belongs_to :product
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{product.name.parameterize}"
  end
  def self.pointcost
        self.count(:point_cost)
  end
end
```

---

The model that calls for the pointcost

```
class PointStoreOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow
  attr_accessible :point_transaction_id, :user_id, :workflow_state ,          :shipping_provider, :tracking_number, :items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items, :class_name => "PointStoreItem"
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :point_transaction
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
  workflow do
    state :cart do
      event :purchase, :transitions_to => :purchased
      event :cancel, :transitions_to => :cancelled
    end
    state :purchased do
      event :ship, :transitions_to => :shipped
    end
    state :shipped
    state :cancelled
  end
  def purchase
    unless self.user.point_balance >= total
      halt "Insufficient point balance"
    else
      self.point_transaction = user.point_transactions.new
      self.point_transaction.point_count = total
      self.point_transaction.save!
      self.save!
    end
  end
  def total
    self.items.pointcost
  end
  def on_cancelled_entry(old_state, event, *args)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the model code that this is in? From the SQL there's obviously a relationship between multiple `ActiveRecords` going on which would help to know about.

Comment: What does the query return if you `select point_store_items.point_cost` instead and you talk straight to the database?

Comment: Thanks Guys for the quick responses.. I have edited the  post to include the models I think are related to the issue. In addition I'll let you know what the query returns shortly.

Comment: @muistooshort if i replace self.count(:point_cost) with select point_store_items.point_cost It returns NameError in PointStore::PointStoreItemsController#buy

Comment: Ask the database directly, push Rails out of the way and look at the data.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to do this, do i call select from the terminal?